# setting memory_limit to 2048M but i keep getting 256M error

Tags: php, memory-limit

I am making a plugin for WP, in that plugin there is backup feature that need to run for large period of time, this part also require large amount of memory limit.

So i have set `ini_set('memory_limit', '2048M');`, `ini_set('max_execution_time', 10000);` in my script and `define( 'WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '2048M' );` in WP config file.

However i keep on getting :
`Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 72 bytes)`

Is it a possibility that the hosting company has a certain limit that i cannot change while run-time ?

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Check if you have permission to change those values!

Comment: How do i check if i have premission ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It is very strange. See my output of `phpinfo()`:

[image]

Hosting provider has raised my limit to 128M (it is not me who set it to 128M), and in reality I have 128M available. According to my understanding of Master Value overriding the Local Value, I should have only 64M.

What is most strange, that neither of these values are affected by `ini_set('memory_limit', '32M');`!!

Using `phpinfo` is easy, just place the following php file to your server:

```
<?php
    phpinfo();
?>
```

Comment: so mine has 128m yet the error is for 256m. so it changed somewhere in the script some how

Comment: @NetaMeta What are both of your values? What is your "local" value? What is your "master" value?

Comment: local 2048, master 128. however when i do some echo ini_get('memory_limit'); i get 256.. this is weird

Comment: I've now search my entire WP installation for memory_limit only found the 2 place i set them.. this is odd.

Comment: @NetaMeta I now discovered it is very strange. In reality I have 128M available. seems that the Local value overrides the Master one... see my updated answer.

Comment: Ah found the problem. It was WP apparently. they set the limit 256. Thanks

Comment: @NetaMeta what do you mean by WP? Where did you find the limit?

Answer (score 0):

> Is it a possibility that the hosting company has a certain limit that i cannot change while run-time ?

This is certainly a possibility, particularly when your hosting was provided as a PHP service. By running `phpinfo();` in the same script, you can check if any of your modifications to increase memory to 2048M had any effect.

Comment: well local value is 2048m, and master is 128M so that weird .

Comment: Did your php provider disable php.ini overrides using an empty user ini file filter?

Comment: I dont know really, but the exhaust memory error is for 256 which means that its not server size - it might be somewhere in the script not sure